# Powershell ; Bulk user import using different UO

Tags: powershell

i have been struggling with a script for a while now and i cant figure it out for the life of me. I am new to Powershell or any sort of scripting for that matter.

I have 3 questions regarding this code.

1. How do i change the $User.username to be the first letter of "Voornaam" and 2 letters of "Achternaam"
2. How do set the OU to be read from "Werkgever".

Simply put ; if variable is A output OU=1....

Else if Variable is B output OU=2....

3. How do i link a manager to a user? Found in the Organization tab - Manager - Name.

If there are any questions please let me know, i'm in desperate need of help! I'm sorry for the bad english since it's not my native tongue
Here is my .csv File.

Werkgever,Mdw.,Naam,Roepnaam,Voorletters,Voorvoegsel,Voornaam,Achternaam,Afdeling,OE,Functie,Mobiel werk,Telnr. werk,Locatie werkzaam,Leidinggevende,In dienst,Uit dienst,Soort medewerker code,Soort medewerker
GP Groot bv,---,John Borg,John,J.,,John,Borg,Algemeen: GPG algemeen,Algemeen: ICT mdw,stagiair,---,,Inzameling Alkmaar,---,1/13/2020,,6,Stagiair

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QNLP.jpg

Here is my code:

```
Import-Module activedirectory

#Store the data from ADUsers.csv in the $ADUsers variable
$ADUsers = Import-csv C:/Eigen_poging_tot_bulkimport.csv

#Loop through each row containing user details in the CSV file 
foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{
    #Read user data from each field in each row and assign the data to a variable as below

    $Voornaam         = $User.firstname
    $Achternaam       = $User.lastname  
    $Voornaam,$Achternaam = $User.username
    $email            = $User.email
    $streetaddress    = $User.streetaddress
    $city             = $User.city
    $zipcode          = $User.zipcode
    $state            = $User.state
    $country          = $User.country
    $Mobiel_werk      = $User.telephone
    $Functie          = $User.jobtitle
    $Werkgever        = $User.company
    $Locatie_werkzaam = $User.department
    $Password         = $User.Password

 if ($Werkgever -eq "GP_Groot_bv")
     {-Path = "OU=01. GP GROOT BV,OU=GP GROOT ORGANISATIE,DC=testomgeving,DC=nl"}      
   ElseIf ($Werkgever  -eq 'GP Groot brandstoffen en oliehandel bv')  
           { $User.OU = 'OU=04. BRANDSTOFFEN EN OLIEHANDEL,OU=GP GROOT ORGANISATIE,DC=testomgeving,DC=nl' }
    ElseIf ($Werkgever  -eq 'NNRD')  
           { -Path = 'OU=07. NNRD,OU=GP GROOT ORGANISATIE,DC=testomgeving,DC=nl' }

             Else {

  'The OU Is not defined properly'

}


    #Check to see if the user already exists in AD
    if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq "$Firstname $Lastname"})
    {
         #If user does exist, give a warning
         Write-Warning "A user account with username $Username already exist in Active Directory."
    }
    else
    {
        #User does not exist then proceed to create the new user account
        New-ADUser `
            -SamAccountName $Username `
            -UserPrincipalName "$Username@testomgeving.nl" `
            -Name "$Firstname $Lastname" `
            -GivenName $Firstname `
            -Surname $Lastname `
            -Enabled $True `
            -DisplayName "$Lastname, $Firstname" `
            -Path `
            -City $city `
            -Company $company `
            -State $state `
            -StreetAddress $streetaddress `
            -OfficePhone $telephone `
            -EmailAddress $email `
            -Title $jobtitle `
            -Department $department `
            -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring "TempPass123!" -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True `
     }       
    }
```

Comment: Please post the sample CSV as text (ie. open it in notepad.exe or similar and copy-paste the contents) rather than screenshots of excel

Answer (score 1):

Put the "Werkgever-to-OU" mappings in a hashtable - this way they're easy to "translate" later:

```bsh
$mapping = @{
    'GP_Groot_bv' = "OU=01. GP GROOT BV,OU=GP GROOT ORGANISATIE,DC=testomgeving,DC=nl"
    'GP Groot brandstoffen en oliehandel bv' = 'OU=04. BRANDSTOFFEN EN OLIEHANDEL,OU=GP GROOT ORGANISATIE,DC=testomgeving,DC=nl'
    'NNRD' = 'OU=07. NNRD,OU=GP GROOT ORGANISATIE,DC=testomgeving,DC=nl'
}
```

Now you can replace your `if/else/elseif` logic with:

```
if(-not $mapping.ContainsKey($Werkgever)){
  Write-Warning 'The OU Is not defined properly'
  continue
}
```

And pass `$mapping[$Werkgever]` to the `-Path` parameter:

```
New-ADUser -Path $mapping[$Werkgever] ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! i've tried to put it all together in one piece, but now it gives me the following error : Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null. At line:51 char:3 + New-ADUser ` + ~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArrayIndex 
Do you have any idea what i did wrong? once again thank you!